# Identifying a specific website in a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make an extension (chrome) that will identify if this is the correct webpage, and then it will load Html/Javascript/Css to that website. Can this be done in a .json file or javascript file? Or other languages to complete this action?

So, if I have it identify Facebook, then it will change some of the html/css/javascript on the website just for me. How can I manage to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your manifest to *match* which websites your extension will run on:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://facebook.com/*", "https://twitter.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
}
```

The `/*` in `facebook.com/*` means that the extension will run on `facebook.com` and any page that belongs to it (e.g. `facebook.com/zuck`).

As you can see I included the JavaScript files I wanted to use for logic in my extension.

I downloaded JQuery from the JQuery website and saved it in the folder of my unpacked extension.

From here see [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript) to assign the url of the current page to a variable in your JavaScript code, using JQuery.

Comment: I'm new to chrome extentions/ json files, could I do the same thing you did with html in the json code?

Comment: For example, I want to change the title of the website in html.

Comment: Sure.  Use JQuery and JavaScript in the new myscript.js file you created to check the current url and then modify the page's html accordingly.